# Logwatch send email to @outlook.com

Tags: postfix, smtp

i just installed Logwatch and used this [guid](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-logwatch-on-ubuntu-desktopserver.html).
But i can't get it to send emails.. I would like to send them to my @outlook.com adress, if possible.
I can't seem to find any guid on google. Do I need to install/configur a SMTP server / postfix?
I'm running Ubuntu server 12.04.4
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run update 7upgrade did fix my problem some how

Answer (score 0):

Any application on the machine will drop mails to the `SMTP` server running on that machine. Your `SMTP` server should be running to deliver the mail. No configurations are required if you just want them to be sent to external addresses like `gmail.com` or `outlook.com`. Try sending a test email with the following command and check your maillog.

```
echo "Test email"|mail -s "test subject" uremail@outlook.com
```

If you receive the test mail, then just specifying `MailTo` in `logwatch.conf` should work.

Comment: tried this, it sad i was missing mail, so i had to install mailutils. after that, did not recive any mail :S

Comment: ok, i have 2 ubuntu servers. One works out of the box, i get mail..
i can do this: sendmail myadress@outlook.com andi wil recive a mail. On server 2 i wil not recive mail. I tok a look at the /etc/postfix/main.cf, and they are alike. Is my Postfix on server 2 unstable?

Comment: Can u paste your maillog? That will help to isolate the problem.

Comment: my mail.log says: smtp failed connection failed, and: sending failed host not found

Comment: Can u edit your question and paste the complete log lines?